# Footnotes in emacs org mode: how to disable [n], but keep [fn:]?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I disable the `[n]` being linked to a footnote and highlighted? `[n] can be many things, like any index of an array. So, I want my footnotes to be`[fn:n]`and only`[fn:n]`.

Answer (score 1):

An [old post to an emacs-orgmode mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-07/msg01255.html) I found suggests one of the two following solutions (I have not tested these) should work:

1. Add `#+DISABLE_PLAIN_FOOTNOTES: some arbitrary text` to your org-mode file.
2. Add to your `.emacs` file:

   ```
   (defun jb/disable-plain-footnotes-hack ()
      (if (plist-get opt-plist :no-plain-footnotes)
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char 1)
           (replace-regexp "\\[\\([0-9]+\\)\\]" "[\u200B\\1]"))))

   (add-to-list 'org-export-inbuffer-options-extra
   '("DISABLE_PLAIN_FOOTNOTES" :no-plain-footnotes))

   (add-hook 'org-export-preprocess-hook
   'jb/disable-plain-footnotes-hack)
   ```

Given the age of the post I found this in, any recent version of emacs org-mode should work with the first solution.

Comment: That won't work in general, it won't export the footnotes, but still treat [n] as one during editing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, so I asked on emacs.SE. Overriding the regular expression functions as in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19284/10677) works nicely. Reproducing this here:

Override the `org-footnote-re` and `org-footnote-definition-re` functions by using this in your .emacs file:

```
(setq org-footnote-definition-re "^\\[fn:[-_[:word:]]+\\]"
      org-footnote-re            (concat "\\[\\(?:fn:\\([-_[:word:]]+\\)?:"
                                         "\\|"
                                         "\\(fn:[-_[:word:]]+\\)\\)"))
```