# Configuring footnotes in emacs org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I came along the post [Footnotes in emacs org mode: how to disable [n], but keep [fn:]?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117924/footnotes-in-emacs-org-mode-how-to-disable-n-but-keep-fn) some months ago, and, as I said there, I don't believe the answer is right.

However, I 'd still like to know how to ignore numeric foot notes (in the form [n]).

The org mode docs say "A plain numeric footnote marker. Compatible with footnote.el, but not recommended because something like ‘[1]’ could easily be part of a code snippet. that". Sadly, it does not explain how to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by modifying `org/lisp/org-footnote.el`

- Comment out a line in definition of 'org-footnote-re'

```lisp
(defconst org-footnote-re
;; Only [1]-like footnotes are closed in this regexp, as footnotes
;; from other types might contain square brackets (i.e. links) in
;; their definition.
;;
;; `org-re' is used for regexp compatibility with XEmacs.
(concat "\\[\\(?:"
    ;; Match inline footnotes.
    (org-re "fn:\\([-_[:word:]]+\\)?:\\|")
    ;; Match other footnotes.
    "\\(?:\\([0-9]+\\)\\]\\)\\|"   ; <-------- comment out this line
    (org-re "\\(fn:[-_[:word:]]+\\)")
    "\\)")
  "Regular expression for matching footnotes.")
```

- Change the argument of function 'org-re' here.

```lisp
(defconst org-footnote-definition-re
  (org-re "^\\[\\([0-9]+\\|fn:[-_[:word:]]+\\)\\]")
  "Regular expression matching the definition of a footnote.")
```

Change string

```lisp
"^\\[\\([0-9]+\\|fn:[-_[:word:]]+\\)\\]"
```

to

```lisp
"^\\[\\(fn:[-_[:word:]]+\\)\\]"
```